# Использование yeild в бесконечном цикле с задержкой

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Рассмотрим следующую функцию:

```
void f()
{
    while(true)
    {
        // do smth
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(60));
    }
}
```

Эта функция исполняется в отдельном потоке. Помимо этой существует еще несколько подобных функций с аналогичным бесконечным циклом и они также исполняются в отдельных потоках.

Вопрос: нужно ли в циклах подобных функций использовать инструкцию yeild и если да то какой эффект будет получен?

Comment: на данный момент ни один из принятых стандартов с++ не поддерживает корутины. Так что уточните вопрос

Comment: В С++ нет инструкций yield. Чего вы вообще хотите тут добиться?

Comment: @VTT https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield а добиться я хочу того, чтобы как либо разгрузить процессор на момент ожидание 60 секунд

Comment: @ VTT как раз по ссылке есть пример кода, где yield используется в цикле, вопрос в том, что делать в случае длительной задержки, как здесь

Comment: `std::this_thread::yield` - это обычная функция (в отличие от другие языков). Во время сна потока процессор и так разгружен и ничего для этого потока не делает. Sleep обычно работает как уведомление для планировщика потоков не выделять этому потоку процессорного времени до истечения указанного интервала.